# IE10 Validation bug with maxlength and placeholder on textbox

Tags: validation, internet-explorer-10, placeholder, maxlength

I have a textbox for Age:

```html
<input type="text" id="txtAge" name="txtAge" class="text" placeholder="Age (optional)" maxlength="2">
```

Upon clicking submit, this input is instantly bordered red. There is no postback. I'm assuming IE10 believes the client has actually typed in "Age (optional)" which is greater than the `maxlength` of 2.

Is there anyway to get around this without making the user do anything in their browser's settings and without removing the `maxlength` attribute?

Comment: It doesn’t sound likely that that is the issue. Does IE10 give an error message on the field? Do you do any custom validation on submit? BTW it might be better if you use type="number" for age.

Comment: IE 10 adds a 3px red border. I don't know from where. I've searched the entire solution for 3px solid red with no result. The submit button doesnt have any javascript tied to it at all. Its supposed to postback in this particular case.  

While using type=number may fix this particular issue, I have other fields like middle initial where placeholder="MI" and maxlength="1" and it shows the same red border.

Comment: Can you post a demo of the issue, as I'm not seeing the issue with just using the code you supplied above?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `novalidate` and `formnovalidate` attributes. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information.

> Internet Explorer 10 and Windows Store apps using JavaScript add new support for HTML5 Forms, including new states of the type attribute (on the input element), new attributes for the input element, and the progress element. This support enables developers to quickly and easily provide user prompting, input validation, and feedback with a minimal amount of script.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673544(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem.

In this case you should change your max length to 10 so it will not be issue for max length and set the max length that you want for your textbox using javascript like following.

```
function setMaxLength(obj, len) {
return (obj.value.length < len);
}
```

and call this function like following

```
<input type="text" id="txtAge" name="txtAge" class="text" placeholder="Age (optional)" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return setMaxLength(this,2);">
```

This will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, in my case it was a GUID field, which was hidden as I didn't need to have it displayed on screen. So I had display:none and maxlength=0.
Yet, IE was performing the validation, the postback was failing and I had no idea why.
It took me half day to figure it out, the solution was to set maxlength=36.

Comment: Same issue here; thanks for your post. I just lost an hour because of a hidden textbox that was populated via client script but had a maxlength that was too small. What sux is that IE 10 (and 11) will block the form submit, and show an error message "your input exceeded X chars" (or whatever), but the error message is hidden because the element was hidden, so user has no way of knowing what is going on. Seems like a bug in IE: if element is hidden, either don't validate maxlength at all, or show as an alert/dialog instead. Really, they should just remove this feature... it's a server-side task