# RadMaskedTextBox does not validating properly in IE 10

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am using telerik masked text box in my registration form, and properties given `mask="###/###-####" MaxLength="10"`.

Html Markup

```
<telerik:RadMaskedTextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" MaxLength="10"     
 BorderColor="Black" Mask="###-###/####" SelectionOnFocus="CaretToBeginning"    
 Width="200px">
```

I have written Javascript for validation working fine for Internet Explorer9.

But Later I have installed IE 10
 It gives error like

> You must enter text with 10 or Fewer Characters

even I have given 123/456-7890(total length)

I have many forms with same problem, please give me correct solutions
May I  add any script files for IE (or) need to change in all the forms.
  I am waiting for your answer.
Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Can you show me your code?

Comment: above code is working fine for IE9 and not working for IE10

Comment: Please check this link [ie10-validation-bug-with-maxlength-and-placeholder-on-textbox][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223832/ie10-validation-bug-with-maxlength-and-placeholder-on-textbox

Comment: Can you show me your `CaretToBeginning` function code?

Comment: <telerik:RadMaskedTextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" MaxLength="10" BorderColor="Black" Mask="###/###-####" SelectionOnFocus="CaretToBeginning" Width="200px">

Comment: Thanks, I got the solutions [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223832/ie10-validation-bug-with-maxlength-and-placeholder-on-textbox)